# is there any XYMHIGHESTMODSEQ documentation?

Tags: imap, yahoo

I've been searching for XYMHIGHESTMODSEQ RFC for a while now but I have never been able to find anything on it, does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: It is a Yahoo proprietary extension, massively simplified from the 'CONDSTORE' RFC.  Roughly, if didn't change from last time you looked, nothing has changed, including message flags.  If it has changed, then something has happened.

Comment: I see... I still wonder how massively simplified it is, since I cannot find any specifics around it. Thanks Max

Comment: When I worked with it, it was just a per-folder cookie that indicated if the folder had any changes.  It doesn’t seem to have any official documentation.